# Kafka: Killing a consumers connection

Tags: apache-kafka

With EMS it is possible to see all connections to a particular EMS server, and kill any unwanted connections.

As far as I can tell, I have an unwanted process somewhere that is subscribing to my Kafka topic with the same consumer name as my process.

Therefore, my process is not receiving any messages and I don't know where this "rogue" process is located.

Is there any command I can run to kill such connections?

I am running Kafka 0.9

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Confluent Control Center you can see each consumer group and all the clients in each consumer group. That might help you identify the "rogue" consumer.

Otherwise you might have to just pick a new group id so it won't matter what the other client is subscribing to (because it will be in another consumer group).

It sounds like you should also configure some security and ACLs so that rogue apps can't authenticate and subscribe to topics they are not allowed to access.

Comment: Unfortunately we are not using Confluent, just plain old Kafka. We are in the process of adding security etc